# Are the builder pattern and a DSL equivalent - or is one more expressive?

Tags: java, scala, clojure, dsl, builder

**Assumptions**

- I'll limit this to [internal DSLs](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/InternalDslStyle.html) - but if you can give me a good reason why I should consider [external DSLs](http://javieracero.com/blog/internal-vs-external-dsl) - I'll listen to that.
- If you want to answer this in Clojure or Scala and explain why I'm wrong - I'm cool with that too.

I heard a friend say the other day:

> You know, a [DSL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-specific_language) and the [builder pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern) - they're basically the same thing.

To me this sounded strange, as I had always assumed a [DSL](http://www.martinfowler.com/bliki/DomainSpecificLanguage.html) would always be more expressive than the Builder Pattern.

My question is: **Are the builder pattern and a DSL equivalent - or is one more expressive?**

So I took a look - here is a [User Builder Pattern in Java](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/01/the-builder-pattern-in-practice.html):

```
public class User {
    private final String firstName; // required
    private final String lastName; // required
    private final int age; // optional
    private final String phone; // optional
    private final String address; // optional

    private User(UserBuilder builder) {
        this.firstName = builder.firstName;
        this.lastName = builder.lastName;
        this.age = builder.age;
        this.phone = builder.phone;
        this.address = builder.address;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public String getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public static class UserBuilder {
        private final String firstName;
        private final String lastName;
        private int age;
        private String phone;
        private String address;

        public UserBuilder(String firstName, String lastName) {
            this.firstName = firstName;
            this.lastName = lastName;
        }

        public UserBuilder age(int age) {
            this.age = age;
            return this;
        }

        public UserBuilder phone(String phone) {
            this.phone = phone;
            return this;
        }

        public UserBuilder address(String address) {
            this.address = address;
            return this;
        }

        public User build() {
            return new User(this);
        }

    }
}
```

Here is the above builder pattern being used:

```
public User getUser() {
    return new
        User.UserBuilder("John", "Doe")
        .age(30)
        .phone("1234567")
        .address("Fake address 1234")
        .build();
}
```

Here is [usage of an Internal DSL in Java](http://www.infoq.com/articles/internal-dsls-java):

```
 Person person = constructor().withParameterTypes(String.class)
                              .in(Person.class)
                              .newInstance("Yoda");

 method("setName").withParameterTypes(String.class)
                  .in(person)
                  .invoke("Luke");

 field("name").ofType(String.class)
              .in(person)
              .set("Anakin");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think that you can even compare these 2 different concepts.

A DSL is a *language* for a specific domain i.e it has primitives and composition rules that allows you to talk about a specific domain.

A builder pattern is a pattern i.e a *solution template* that you *apply* to a problem to come up with a solution and then you use that solution. In your code example, the UserBuilder class comes out of applying the builder pattern, it itself is not builder pattern.

It seems that you are trying to compare them syntactically as your sample code is trying to show. In both the example code you show that syntactically, both DSL and a builder patter class, have the same feature i.e a chain of method calls and that leads to the thought that you can compare them. I don't think that comparison is fair as that can only allow you to compare them in a same language i.e there is no way to compare them syntactically across different programming languages.

You can implement a DSL using the builder pattern OR you can also implement DSL using other patterns too. A pattern is a solution template for a set of problems, builder pattern is one such template for the problem of implementing a DSL but it is not the only one.

Comment: Thanks @Ankur - that's really helpful. (It is what I was thinking too). Can I ask for an example of where a DSL is more expressive?

Comment: @hawkeye: The concept of expressiveness is very hard to express ;). Lets say you are building a financial application and you also want the user of the app to create custom rules that allows the customization of app. In that case building a DSL for users to express their rules will lead to more expressiveness than asking user to write rules in the native language of the app i.e the language in which the app was written.

Comment: In the Arc challenge (http://www.paulgraham.com/arcchallenge.html) Paul Graham frames expressiveness as being able to express the most number of functions with the fewest instructions- he uses 'nodes'). If we use 'nodes' - can we say that DSLs are more expressive than the builder pattern - or will they always be the same?

Comment: A DSL will have a set of instructions and hence you can compute its expressiveness using PG approach. A builder pattern doesn't have instructions, rather what you create using builder pattern will have instructions and hence what you create using builder pattern have expressiveness not the builder pattern itself.

Answer (score 0):

Of course DSLs include a lot of things which aren't a builder pattern. So no, they aren't the same thing.

*If* you consider every builder pattern to be a DSL (for the domain of constructing objects of a particular class), then you obviously get that DSLs in general are more expressive than builder patterns. But *a* DSL is not more expressive than the builder pattern; any single DSL can't do everything that the builder pattern can do.

Answer (score 0):

Had your friend said

> You know, *for constructing [Plain Old Java Objects](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_Old_Java_Object)*, the builder pattern is a kind of DSL.

... then I'd agree.

However, in Clojure, you don't need a builder class or a DSL to construct an object concisely.

- POJOs translate into records, which imitate (hash) maps. There is a somewhat clunky
  syntax for creating a record from a map.

Given

```
(defrecord User [first-name last-name age phone address])
```

... then

```
(map->User {:first-name "John"
            :last-name "Doe"
            :address "Fake address 1234"})
```

... produces

```
{:first-name "John",
 :last-name "Doe",
 :age nil,
 :phone nil,
 :address "Fake address 1234"}
```

... which is a `User` record, though it prints like a map.

So, for this purpose, Clojure takes the *DS* out of *DSL* and you're just left with a language construct.